# had pp with that-clause : had expected that I would have got

Tags: tense

I have english sentence writing problem

> The only reason I agreed to do that with you is because I **had expected** that I **would have got** some profit.

I have confused about tenses of two parts : Since we use the past tense 'agreed', so I think that we have to use had pp 'had expected'. And I think that it is right. Main problem is following : I used 'would have got' because I think that 'would have pp' may means 'will + had pp'. Am I right ?

Comment: We don't need to use the past perfect. The speaker expected to make a profit **at the time** that they made the agreement - it's not 'one action earlier than another'.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. If so, I want to add some question. The following sentence is true ? The only reason I followed him is because he had told me that I would be a doctor. (=because he had said to me "You will be a doctor")

Comment: You mean 'Is the sentence _correct_?' - I can't say whether it's _true_ or not. Yes, it's correct if the speaker had already been told that when they decided to follow.

Comment: I appreciate your careful reading and answer.